# How get the output from one maven plugin into another?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, ecj

I currently run the Eclipse Java compiler (ECJ) plugin in Maven in order to scan my code for errors and warnings. I want to design a plugin for Maven that is able to take in all the errors and warnings found by the ECJ in order to parse through them.

I am stuck on how to go about reading the ECJ output. My first instinct was to output it to a file and have my plugin read that file, but there must be a better way I can pass the ECJ output into my custom plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Maven's architecture does not envision any flow of significant amounts of data other than through files. Plugins run in isolated class loaders with very limited interaction with each other.